# How to predict with feature with different datatypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I have a set of data like (Date,Quantity,Category,Country,State,Unit Price, Net Sales, Total Profit)

Can you guys help me with python code how can I use all the feature to predict "Total Profit". The features have different datatypes. I have tried many approaches but no luck.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The type of machine learning (ML) problem that you are trying to solve is an ML-regression problem. There are a lot of models that one could try.

I would suggest you try using Random Forest regressor. Take a look at this medium post: [A Beginners Guide to Random Forest Regression](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/random-forest-regression-9871bc9a25eb).

Your primary friend in such cases would **`scikit-learn`** library. You would benefit a lot from this kaggle micro-course on Machine Learning: [Intermediate Machine Learning](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intermediate-machine-learning).

You may want to take a look at some ML courses on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/random-forest-algorithm-in-machine-learning/) and [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/practical-machine-learning/random-forests-XKsl6).

I hope this helps.

Comment: given OP's obvious lack of experience, I think pointing them to relatively simple linear-regressions would be a better starting point than random forests which involve another level of complexity

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to do data engineering for independent features (Date,Quantity,Category,Country,State,Unit Price, Net Sales) then you can apply machine learning model to predict target variable(Total Profit).

The article might helps for you it has clear descrption about what is EDA and how can handle different variables
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/guide-data-exploration/

Once you done with data engineering you apply regression models(linear, Random forest or svm ...)